# Shopping List SpeechRecognition bugs

Tags: javascript, function, speech-recognition

I created shoppingList where i implemented SpeechRecognition to add new products by voice. It works but i also have a few bugs with that. After i add products (3products for example) and click on stop speak button SpeechRecognition still works one product more and then stop. why it doesn't stop immediately after clicking the button? Second issue: way to see a bug: add some products by voice > click on stop button > click on start button and add a product(product will duplicate e.g if you say milk to product will add milk 2 times.
link do livedemo: https://jakubsoldek.github.io/ShoppingList/

js code below

```js
window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.lang = 'pl-PL';

let click = false;

speechBtn.addEventListener('click', addProductViaSpeech);
stopSpeechBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

    click = !click;
    console.log(click);
    console.log(recognition);
})

recognition.addEventListener('end', () => click ? recognition.stop() : recognition.start());


function addProductViaSpeech(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("dziala chwile");
    // recognition.stop();
    recognition.start();
    recognition.addEventListener('result', e => {
        const transcript = Array.from(e.results).map(result => result[0]).map(result => result.transcript).join('');
        console.log(transcript);
        if (e.results[0].isFinal) {
            const productDiv = document.createElement("div");
            productDiv.classList.add("product");

            const newProduct = document.createElement('li');
            newProduct.innerText = transcript;
            newProduct.classList.add('product-text');

            productDiv.appendChild(newProduct);
            //local storage
            console.log(newProduct.innerText);
            saveLocalTodos(newProduct.innerText);

            const productPrice = document.createElement("li");
            productPrice.classList.add("product-price");
            const priceProductInput = document.createElement("input");
            priceProductInput.classList.add("price-product-input");
            // console.log(priceProductInput);
            priceProductInput.placeholder = "$";
            productDiv.appendChild(productPrice);
            productPrice.appendChild(priceProductInput);

            const trashButton = document.createElement("button");
            trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>';
            trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
            productDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
            productList.appendChild(productDiv);

            productInput.value = "";

            quantityJs++;
            quantity.innerText = quantityJs;

            productInput.classList.add("warning");
            productInput.placeholder = "can't be empty";

            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                // console.log(arr[i]);
                arr[i].addEventListener('change', findTotal);
            }
        }
    });
}
```